# How to include all objects of an archive in a shared object?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, archive

When compiling our project, we create several archives (static libraries), say `liby.a` and `libz.a` that each contains an object file defining a function `y_function()` and `z_function()`. Then, these archives are joined in a shared object, say `libyz.so`, that is one of our main distributable target.

```
g++  -fPIC  -c -o y.o y.cpp
ar cr liby.a y.o
g++  -fPIC  -c -o z.o z.cpp
ar cr libz.a z.o
g++ -shared -L. -ly -lz -o libyz.so
```

When using this shared object into the example program, say `x.c`, the link fails because of an undefined references to functions `y_function()` and `z_function()`.

```
g++ x.o -L. -lyz -o xyz
```

It works however when I link the final executable directly with the archives (static libraries).

```
g++ x.o -L. -ly -lz -o xyz
```

My guess is that the object files contained in the archives are not *linked* into the shared library because they are not used in it. How to force inclusion?

Edit:

Inclusion can be forced using --whole-archive `ld` option. But if results in compilation errors:

```
g++ -shared '-Wl,--whole-archive' -L. -ly -lz -o libyz.so
/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS): In function `__libc_csu_init':
(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `__init_array_end'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined hidden symbol `__init_array_end' can not be used when making a shared object
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
```

Any idea where this comes from?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could try (ld(2)):

```
   --whole-archive
       For each archive mentioned on the command line after the --whole-archive option, include every object file in the
       archive in the link, rather than searching the archive for the required object files.  This is normally used to turn
       an archive file into a shared library, forcing every object to be included in the resulting shared library.  This
       option may be used more than once.
```

(gcc -Wl,--whole-archive)

Plus, you should put `-Wl,--no-whole-archive` at the end of the library list. (as said by  Dmitry Yudakov in the comment below)

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I'm looking for, but it generates a link error I cannot figure where it comes from. I added details in the question.

Comment: there's importnat note in `man ld` for this option: don't forget to use -Wl,-no-whole-archive after your list of archives, because gcc will add its own list of archives to your link and you may not want this flag to affect those as well