# GCC: --whole-archive and --no-whole-archive options

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker

I am creating a shared object library from two `*.a` (static libraries) using GCC. I referred these articles:

1. [How to force gcc to link an unused static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116420/how-to-force-gcc-to-link-an-unused-static-library)
2. [How to include all objects of an archive in a shared object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763988/how-to-include-all-objects-of-an-archive-in-a-shared-object)

and created a command line as:

```
gcc -shared -o libmain.so main.o  -Wl,--whole-archive -lgdiplus -lsqlite3 -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

Here `main.o` is compiled with `-fPIC` option and used for linking to create final output file called `libmain.so`. But when I checked my output, it seems to be empty:

```
$># nm libmain.so
00000000002005d0 a _DYNAMIC
0000000000200788 a _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
00000000002005a8 d __CTOR_END__
00000000002005a0 d __CTOR_LIST__
00000000002005b8 d __DTOR_END__
00000000002005b0 d __DTOR_LIST__
0000000000000598 r __FRAME_END__
00000000002005c0 d __JCR_END__
00000000002005c0 d __JCR_LIST__
00000000002007a8 A __bss_start
                 w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000000500 t __do_global_ctors_aux
0000000000000440 t __do_global_dtors_aux
00000000002005c8 d __dso_handle
                 w __gmon_start__
00000000002007a8 A _edata
00000000002007b8 A _end
0000000000000538 T _fini
00000000000003e0 T _init
0000000000000420 t call_gmon_start
00000000002007b0 b completed.6145
00000000002007a8 b dtor_idx.6147
00000000000004ec T foo
00000000000004c0 t frame_dummy
```

Ideally this should contain all the symbols from both `*.a files`, right?

Can anybody guide what is wrong here? I am using RHEL 5.5 x64 and GCC 4.1.2.

Thanks,
Omkar

Comment: Name the archives on the command line explicitly, i.e. /path/to/libsqlite3.a instead of -lsqlite3. Note you need the libraries built with -fPIC as well.

Comment: Why use gcc when all you want to use is ld?

Comment: You're probably _not_ using the static libraries.

Answer (score -1):

try：

```
gcc -shared -o libmain.so main.o  -Wl,--whole-archive gdiplus sqlite3 -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```