# C++ pluggable source files not linked

Tags: c++

I write software with plugins that can be abled or disabled in compile time. In its source file, a plugin registers itself by declaring a static const registry variable whose constructor adds the plugin's creator to a table. The main part of the program doesn't call a plugin's method directly.

For example, in `PluginRegistry.cpp`

```cpp
struct PluginDesc {
    PluginDesc(std::string_view name,
               std::string_view desc): mName(name), mDesc(desc) {
        regPlugin(this);    // add instance to table
    }
    
    std::string_view name;
    std::string_view desc;
}
```

and in a plugin file `PluginA.cpp`

```cpp
static const desc = PluginDesc("pluginA", "a plugin");  // try to register itself
```

But I cannot create any plugin even if Ninja shows it's been compiled unless I include the plugin's header and use some functions declared in it. Is it a result of the linker's optimization? If I have to include all plugins' headers, it's not pluggable anymore. How can I fix it?

**Update**: If the program link plugin library as static link, the creation will always fail, but dynamic link has no problem.

Comment: Could you explain what a plugin is? or maybe you're missing tags? Ninja?

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]? No need to copy a substantial portion of your code, just show how you define the static const variable and its constructor (the latter cah just print a message).

Comment: @CedricMartens I added an example code snippet. I don't know if the word plugin is proper, it's loaded in compile time instead of runtime.

Comment: Please post something we can copy, paste and compile with **no** change

Comment: @n.m. I create a new demo repo to describe it: https://github.com/TsaiHao/plugin_demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are placing your plugin in a static library, while your main program contains no references to that library. The library will not be linked by default.

You have several options:

- place plugins in object files rather than libraries
- use gcc flag `-Wl,--whole-archive` at the linking stage as explained e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30438812/gcc-whole-archive-and-no-whole-archive-options)
- place plugins in dynamic libraries and load them at run time

Edit: the main program does contain a reference to the *library* but not to the needed *object* in the library, so that *object* (`a.o`) is not linked.

Comment: Is invoking `createPlugin` in main not considered a "reference" to the static plugin library?

Comment: See the edit. You place `createPlugin` in a wrong place. It should be in the main program, not in any plugin library (otherwise you will have problems if you have more than one plugin).