# Link static library to shared library or to a binary

Tags: meson-build

I have a static library from the project `A` (let's call it `liba.so`) and I want to compile a shared library in my project `B` (let's call it `libb.so`) and embed `liba.so` in it.

Also, I have a binary in that project `B` which also depends on `liba.so`, so I want to embed it in the binary.

Is that possible? How?

Comment: Are you sure project A creates a static library ? liba.so is the name of a shared library, which you cannot embed into another shared library - liba.a would be a proper name for a static library. However, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763988/how-to-include-all-objects-of-an-archive-in-a-shared-object

Comment: @nos Indeed, you're right. It's `liba.a`. So I should compile `libb.a`. Anyways, I'm still not sure how to make meson do it.

Comment: please update the question with `liba.a` as appropriate. This is confusing as is

Answer (score 5):

**When A is a Separate Code Base**

What you do is build and install project A. Then create a dependency on project A in project B's definition.

That looks like this:

```
a_dep = dependency('a', version : '>=1.2.8')    
lib_b = shared_library('proj_b', sources: 'prog_b.c', dependencies : a_dep)
```

The version section in `dependency` is optional.

**When A is in the Same Meson Project as B**

When A and B are in the same meson project, it's a little uglier. You have to declare a dependency anchor in A.

That looks like this:

```
incdirs = include_directories('include')
lib_a = static_library('a', 'proj_a.c', include_directories : indirs)

liba_dependency = declare_dependency(
   include_directories : incdirs,
   link_with : lib_a,
   sources : ['proj_a.c'])
```

Then project B becomes:

```
lib_b = shared_library('proj_b', sources: 'prog_b.c', dependencies : lib_a)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have an **existing, precompiled** library, then you can directly wrap it in a `dependency`:

```
cpp = meson.get_compiler('cpp')

# (Meson requires an absolute path for find_library().)
libdir = meson.current_source_dir() + './lib/

precompiledA_dep = cpp.find_library('A', dirs : libdir) # ./lib/libA.lib

...
# Link against libA.lib here ...
B_lib = library('libB', 'libB.cpp', dependencies : precompiledA_dep)
B_exe = executable('exeB', 'source.cpp', dependencies : precompiledA_dep)
```

(tested with Meson 0.57)